# SQL Server 2008 Local Connection String

Tags: sql-server-2008, tcp, database-connection, connection-string

I'm attempting to run unit tests *locally* via connecting to SQL Server 2008 in my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

I have the following two connection strings -- the first one does not work, but the second one does work.

```
DOES NOT WORK
Data Source=XX.YY.ZZ.AAA;Initial Catalog=db_name;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

WORKS
Data Source=myserver1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_name;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

**The only difference is the Data Source property!**  The second one works, but the first one does not.  I assume the connection tries to go over TCP to actually connect to the SQL server, but should this prevent me from actually logging in?

Comment: The 1st omits the instance name ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I add the instance name \SQLEXPRESS, I am no longer able to even connect to the server at all... I get a network error rather than a login error. Furthermore, when I use that connection string from a remote computer, it doesn't require the instance name.